# Compiled Formula is too big : Also does not work under Workflow criteria

Tags: workflow, formula, customsetting, field-update

Formula to compute the value of Office__c is as follows.

```
CASE( Account__r.Office__c ,
"Americas","Americas",
"EMEA","EMEA",
"China", "China",
"Hongkong", "Hongkong",
"Taiwan", "Taiwan",
"Korea", "Korea",
"Japan", "Japan",
"India", "India",
"Australia", "Australia",
"Rest of APAC", "Rest of APAC",
"Corporate")
```

The following formula does not work. PQFMap__c is a custom setting hierarchy. I want to generate a single value relevant to a particular region's office. For example I can have Japan's value. This is the purpose to go with custom setting. I also tried this with CASE but the result was the same. Any help will be appreciable.

```
IF(Office__c = "Americas", $Setup.PQFMap__c.Americas__c,
IF(Office__c = "EMEA",  $Setup.PQFMap__c.EMEA__c,
IF(Office__c = "Corporate",  $Setup.PQFMap__c.Corporate__c,
IF(Office__c = "Australia",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.Australia__c,
IF(Office__c = "China",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.China__c,
IF(Office__c = "Hongkong",  $Setup.PQFMap__c.Hongkong__c,
IF(Office__c = "Taiwan",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.Taiwan__c,
IF(Office__c = "Korea",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.Korea__c,   
IF(Office__c = "Japan",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.Japan__c,
IF(Office__c = "India",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.India__c,
IF(Office__c = "Rest of APAC",   $Setup.PQFMap__c.Rest_of_APAC__c,""

)))))))))))
```

Comment: Are any of these other custom fields that you are referencing in this formula formula fields?

Comment: @cmmoutes13 These are all for now which I've to use in the formula.

Comment: What he meant was:  is `Office__c` a formula field? If so, can you include it in the question.

Comment: @NickCook It is a custom field which will have a value e.g Americas, EMEA etc. And for each I've a value stored in a custom settings already which I need to save in formula field. Formula Field name is not referred here. It is just the criteria I write here.

Comment: ok.  The main reason for getting the 'Complied Formula it too big' error is due to a formula field referencing another formula field.  Have you tried doing this in a workflow rule instead?

Comment: @NickCook You are right. Office__c is also a formula field. I've a picklist in the user object. Can I use that is there any chance to get errors from using that picklist field?

Comment: Can you include the formula for `Office__c` in the question?

Comment: @NickCook Formula to compute the value of Office__c is in the question now.

Comment: Is there any reason you even have the `Office__c` field?  The mapping keys look the same as the values.

Comment: @NickCook It is done by the previous dev. I just joined the project two days back.

Comment: @NickCook May be because of the picklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go with the suggestion of Nick above but you can also try this without custom setting. I see use of custom setting is exaggerating here. Instead you can easily do it with another formula field. Because you already tracking the region in one of your fields.

Just create a map of region to quantity value and use the CASE statement in the formula to track the relevant field for each occurrence. Like this.

```
CASE( Account__r.Office__c ,
"Americas", Product__r.Available_Qty_Americas__c,
"EMEA", Product__r.Available_Qty_EMEA__c,
"Corporate", Product__r.Available_Qty_EMEA__c,
"Australia", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"China", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"Hongkong", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"Taiwan", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"Korea", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"Japan", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"India", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
"Rest of APAC", Product__r.Available_Qty_APAC__c,
0)
```

Answer (score 2):

When Salesforce calculates the formula size, it includes any formulas referenced from the formula, within the formula.  So think of substituting the `Office__c` variable with the content of the `Office__c` formula with each occurence of it.

In your case, I'd just replace `Office__c` with `Account__r.Office__c` and use the case statement.  It works better with picklist values.

i.e.

```
Case(Account__r.Office__c,
    "Americas", $Setup.PQFMap__c.Americas__c,
    "EMEA",  $Setup.PQFMap__c.EMEA__c,
    ...
    ...,
    "Default Value")
```

Having said that, I would have assumed using `CASE` would have gotten around this as well, because your `Office__c` formula really isn't that complex.

Comment: Account__r.Office__c is a picklist. Will it give the correct value for each user? Because it can't be same for every user.

Comment: What object is `Office__c` on?

Comment: Account object. And I have a look up from this (Samples object) to Account object.

Comment: How is the Samples object relevant to the Office__c field then?

Comment: Samples object has a lookup field to the Account. And this is the only relevance samples object has to Account.

Comment: Have you tried this? I can't tell by your questions whether you've tried anything, or are just asking questions

Comment: Office__c is a picklist in the Account object. Samples object has a lookup to Product object. Each sample request needs to detect the Account's office so that we can record that from which location this sample request came. 

I've a question which you can understand. I stored the Product object's fields names in custom settings hierarchy. And now computed each field name in formula field with the relevance of Office. Now how I can get the computed field name's value in the samples object?